# How can I identify that an AWS Lambda was created using the AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm looking for a way to identify that a AWS Lambda was provisioned with the AWS CDK. Is there a tag, or some other type of metadata to identify this? SAM provides a tag `lambda_createdBy:SAM`. I could add a tag myself, but for the case of an organization that has thousands of Lambdas already provisioned identifying this requires changing code for all of them.

Comment: Can't you check their tags if you already have such functions?

Comment: They don't have any particular tags

Comment: So you already know the answer to your question. The only other choice would be possibly an auto-generated function name of specific format if CDK uses them.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK CDK doesn't add any special CDK specific tag. I believe some resource get auto tagged with the CF template they are a part of though so there's that.

Rather than modify the code across the board you can instead write a [CDK Aspect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/aspects.html) that adds the tag to any lambda functions in the app.

Something like:

```
class FunctionTagger implements IAspect {
  public visit(node: IConstruct): void {
    if (node instanceof lambda.Function) {
      Tags.add('myTag', 'myValue', node)
    }
  }
}

// Apply to the stack
stack.node.applyAspect(new FunctionTagger());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda func deployed by CDK will be propagated the tag with key `aws:cloudformation:stack-name`.

Then you can check if the stack with resource named `CDKMetadata`. For example,

```sh
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resource --stack-name my-stack-name --logical-resource-id CDKMetadata
```